clase Runner con JunitPlataform, cucumber
estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, estoy configurando la clase runner con junit 5 cucumber y selenium, pero no encuentra los steps,  no me doy cuenta de que puede estar pasando, alguien que me pueda tirar una luz? estoy dejo cap de mis directorios y runner, probé de varias formas pero no arranca
aclaro que tambien estoy usando junit 4 y el runner del mismo anda ok.
.
directorios

package pages;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("feature")
//@ConfigurationParameter(key = "cucumber.glue",value = "com.steps")
//@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME,value = "feature")//archivos .feature
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME,value = "steps")//steps
//@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME,value = "@googleSearch")
//@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.EXECUTION_DRY_RUN_PROPERTY_NAME,value = "false")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME,value =
        "pretty, json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json, html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html")

public class Runner2 {

}

